# std::for_each with function object

Tags: c++, algorithm

The following piece of code produces a very strange output and I have no idea why. 
It is supposed to be a very primitive benchmark for my other test programs. Whatever executable is passed as cmd line parameter is executed a couple of times and clock cycles are counted, then mean and stddev are calculated (well, not fully implemented yet, but you get the idea).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

class SRS{
public:
  SRS(double p1):mean(p1), srs(0.0){std::cout << this->mean << std::endl;} //DEBUG
  double operator()(unsigned p1){
    this->srs += std::pow(this->mean - (double)p1, 2.0);
    std::cout << p1 << "    " << this->srs << std::endl; //DEBUG
  }
  double getSrs(){
    return this->srs;
  }
private:
  double mean;
  double srs;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  unsigned nCyc;
  if(argc<3){nCyc=1000;}else{nCyc=std::stoi(argv[2]);}
  std::vector<clock_t> c{};
  for(unsigned u = 0; u<nCyc; u+=1){
    clock_t t = clock();
    system(argv[1]); //this is stupid and dangerous
    t = clock() - t;
    c.push_back(t);
  }
  clock_t clkSum = std::accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), 0);
  double clkMean = (double)clkSum / (double)nCyc;
  SRS srs(clkMean);
  std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), srs);
  std::cout << "The program ran for " << clkMean << " +/- " << srs.getSrs() << " clock cycles" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

What puzzles me is that srs.getSrs() always returns whatever value is assigned to SRS::srs by the c'tor (which is 0.0 here). 
Either std::for_each is evaluated after the output for the streams is created or std::for_each reverts the function object to its former status after execution?

Comment: `std::for_each`, like most (all?) algorithms in the standard library, accepts function objects *by value*.

Comment: FYI your `operator()` is defined to return a `double` but you don't return anything. The `for_each` shouldn't be using it but it's still UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The predicate parameter of [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is a value, meaning the algorithm uses a copy of the functor passed as argument. If you want to examine its state, you can use the copy returned to you:

```
SRS ret = std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), srs);
std::cout << "The program ran for " << clkMean 
          << " +/- " << ret.getSrs() << " clock cycles" << std::endl;
```

Comment: That's weird, I never realized `for_each` returned something.